# Is this a picture of particle board?

Tags: flooring

[image] I’m looking underneath the laminate in my kitchen and need to identify this subfloor. Is this particle board?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Another, closer picture of a bare area would really help us help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

That has a high probability of being particle board. You can doublecheck by looking at where the big gouges are... if the material is small flakes/big sawdust, then it's particle board. (Destructive triplecheck by putting a puddle of water on top and seeing if it puckers up.)

Given that you've got a fair bit of damage, now might be the time to replace it all with some water resistant plywood.